# Wrong Recursion for Hangman in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I got a little problem with my haskell code:

```
import Prelude

hangman :: String -> IO ()
hangman [] = return ()
hangman s = do putStr ("Secret: " ++ text s ++ "\n")
               putStr "Enter a character: "
               charr <- getChar 
               function s charr (text s)

function :: String -> Char -> String -> IO ()
function [] _ _          = return ()
function (a:bc) charr (g:jt) = do putStr ("Secret: " ++ (textBack (a:bc) charr (g:jt)) ++ "\n")
                                  putStr "Enter a character: "
                                  charbaby <- getChar
                                  putStr "\n" 
                                  function (a:bc) charbaby (textBack (a:bc) charbaby (g:jt))
                                                  
text :: String -> String
text []     = ""
text (x:ys) = "*" ++ text ys

textBack :: String -> Char -> String -> String
textBack [] _ _              = ""
textBack (a:bc) charr (g:jt) = if charr == a
                                then charr : textBack bc charr jt 
                                else g : textBack bc charr jt
```

And here is the output:

```
*Main> hangman "hello"
Secret: *****
Enter a character: h
Secret: h****
Enter a character:
Secret: h****
Enter a character: e

Secret: he***
Enter a character:
Secret: he***
Enter a character: l

Secret: hell*
Enter a character:
Secret: hell*
Enter a character: o

Secret: hello
Enter a character:
Secret: hello
Enter a character:
```

And as you can see there are some lines which are called multiple times and I dont know why.
I hope you can help me :)

Thank you,

Finn

Comment: Why do you duplicate logic in `hangman` and `function`?

Comment: The reason this is done is because `getChar` takes *one* character, but the enter, is also a character.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Its a different secret-String in the first call

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Damn thanks. I would never have thought of that. But how would i fix this?

Comment: @Finn You could fix it by using `getLine` instead, which reads a whole line rather than a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making it yourself difficult by two things:

1. you duplicate logic in `hangman` and `function`. This makes it hard to keep things in sync; and
2. you are using unnecessary pattern matching making the function less elegant.

For the real problem, I think that this is due to the use of `getChar`: `getChar` takes a single character from the stdin, and if you write for example <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then you thus enter two characters: `'h'` and `'\n'`.

You thus better use [**`getLine`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine) and then use only the first character, or ask to enter the input again when the user has written multiple characters. For example:

```
readGuess :: String -> Maybe Char
readGuess [x] = Just x
readGuess _ = Nothing

getGuess :: IO Char
getGuess = do
    putStrLn "Enter a character:"
    cs <- readGuess <$> getLine
    case cs of
        Just c -> pure c
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid guess" >> getGuess
```

This thus will retrieve a guess with:

```
Prelude> getGuess 
Enter a character:

Invalid guess
Enter a character:
hello
Invalid guess
Enter a character:
foo
Invalid guess
Enter a character:
b
'b'
```

You can simplify `hangman` to:

```
hangman :: String -> IO ()
hangman s = hangman' s (text s)

hangman' :: String -> String -> IO ()
hangman' sa sb
    | sa == sb = putStrLn "You won"
    | otherwise = do
        putStr ("Secret: " ++ sb ++ "\n")
        g <- getGuess
        hangman' sa (textBack sa g sb)
```